# vuejs ckeditor TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')

Tags: ckeditor

I use vuejs and ckeditor.

I get an error when I go to the page with ckeditor. The editor does not display on the page at all.

Can you help me please?

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')
> at IconView._updateXMLContent (app.js:89727:24)
> at IconView.render (app.js:89703:8)
> at IconView. (app.js:107630:32)
> at IconView.fire (app.js:105106:30)
> at IconView. [as render] (app.js:107634:16)
> at ViewCollection._renderViewIntoCollectionParent (app.js:98321:9)
> at ViewCollection. (app.js:98182:9)
> at ViewCollection.fire (app.js:105106:30)
> at ViewCollection.addMany (app.js:101049:9)
> at ViewCollection.add (app.js:101014:15)

here is my dependencies

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-alignment": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-autoformat": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-basic-styles": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-block-quote": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils": "^24.4.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin": "^24.4.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-editor-classic": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-essentials": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-font": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-heading": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-highlight": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-image": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-indent": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-link": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-list": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-page-break": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paragraph": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-paste-from-office": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-remove-format": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-table": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-typing": "^27.1.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue2": "^1.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^5.2.4",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.8",
    "npm": "^6.14.13",
    "postcss-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "raw-loader": "^4.0.2",
    "style-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "vue": "^2.6.12",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.6.0",
    ...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "~4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "~4.5.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "node-sass": "^4.7.2",
    "postcss": "^8.2.10",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^3.1.2",
    "sass": "^1.34.0",
    "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
    "vue-loader": "^15.9.6",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.11",
    "webpack": "^5.26.2",
    ...
  },
```

here is my webpack file

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const path = require('path');

const CKEditorWebpackPlugin = require('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-webpack-plugin');
const { styles } = require( '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-dev-utils' );
const CKERegex = {
    svg: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\]icons[/\\][^/\\]+\.svg$/,
    css: /ckeditor5-[^/\\]+[/\\]theme[/\\].+\.css$/,
};

/*
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 | Mix Asset Management
 |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
 |
 | Mix provides a clean, fluent API for defining some Webpack build steps
 | for your Laravel application. By default, we are compiling the Sass
 | file for the application as well as bundling up all the JS files.
 |
 */

    Mix.listen('configReady', webpackConfig => {
        const rules = webpackConfig.module.rules;
        const targetSVG = /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/;
        const targetFont = /(\.(woff2?|ttf|eot|otf)$|font.*\.svg$)/;
        const targetCSS = /\.css$/;
    
        // exclude CKE regex from mix's default rules
        for (let rule of rules) {
            if (rule.test.toString() === targetSVG.toString()) {
                rule.exclude = CKERegex.svg;
            }
            else if (rule.test.toString() === targetFont.toString()) {
                rule.exclude = CKERegex.svg;
            }
            else if (rule.test.toString() === targetCSS.toString()) {
                rule.exclude = CKERegex.css;
            }
        }
    });
    
    mix
        .webpackConfig({
            resolve: {
                alias: {
                    '@components': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/components/'),
                    '@pages': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/pages/'),
                    '@router': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/router/'),
                    '@store': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js/store/')
                }
            },
            plugins: [
                new CKEditorWebpackPlugin({
                    language: 'fr',
                    additionalLanguages: 'all'
                }),
            ],
            module: {
                rules: [
                    {
                        test: CKERegex.svg,
                        use: ['raw-loader'],
                    },
                    {
                        test: CKERegex.css,
                        use: [
                            {
                                loader: 'postcss-loader',
                                options: styles.getPostCssConfig({
                                    themeImporter: {
                                        themePath: require.resolve('@ckeditor/ckeditor5-theme-lark'),
                                    },
                                    minify: true,
                                }),
                            },
                        ],
                    }
                ],
            }
        });
    
    mix
        .js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
        .vue();
```

Comment: I really need help, does anyone have an idea please ?

Comment: I really need help please? Are you missing any information ?Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I came across the same error and managed to find the solution. You may also solve the problem, so I'll share the way.

In your webpack file(I assume it's webpack.mix.js in your laravel project root), set targetSVG /(.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp|avif)$|^((?!font).)*.svg$)/ instead of /(.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$|^((?!font).)*.svg$)/.

```
- const targetSVG = /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/;
+ const targetSVG = /(\.(png|jpe?g|gif|webp|avif)$|^((?!font).)*\.svg$)/;
```

I found this solution through debugging by adding console.log(rule.test.toString()) inside the for (let rule of rules) loop.

A few years ago, I used Laravel7 with Vue2 and could use CKEditor5 with the older version settings(without "avif"). But now I use Laravel8 with Vue2 and TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute') occurs with the older version settings.

I hope you can use CKEditor5!

Comment: it works! I love you xD I didn't believe it at all but thank you thank you thank you !!!!