# Vue 3 CKEditor 5 Install from Online Builder is not working

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, single-page-application, wysiwyg, ckeditor5

i am following their [docs](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/vuejs-v3.html#integrating-a-build-from-the-online-builder) for adding my custom build to vue 3, here is my component

```
//in script setup
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'
import ClassicEditor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor'

const editor = ClassicEditor
const ckeditor = CKEditor.component

//in template
<ckeditor :editor="editor" v-model="data.content"></ckeditor>
```

i got error that said The requested module `'/ck5/build/ckeditor.js' does not provide an export named 'default'` then i tried `import {Editor} and import {ClassicEditor}` neither of them works. then i tried import from src since i thought it was because of vite and seems like it works (there is no error about importing again neither default or named) but i got another error :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')
    at IconView._updateXMLContent (iconview.js:100:24)
    at IconView.render (iconview.js:76:8)
    at IconView.<anonymous> (observablemixin.js:212:41)
    at IconView.fire (emittermixin.js:170:43)
    at <computed> [as render] (observablemixin.js:215:25)
    at ViewCollection._renderViewIntoCollectionParent (viewcollection.js:204:9)
    at ViewCollection.<anonymous> (viewcollection.js:65:9)
    at ViewCollection.fire (emittermixin.js:170:43)
    at ViewCollection.addMany (collection.js:150:18)
    at ViewCollection.add (collection.js:118:21)
```

What should i do?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70787904/vuejs-ckeditor-typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-null-reading-getattribute
Can this help you?

Comment: @fchancel since i'm not using webpack and laravel mix, no its not.

Answer (score 2):

you must using [online builder](https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/)

1. download your custom build from online builder
2. put it on the root of the assets folder, named 'ckeditor5' or whatever you like
3. yarn add file:./src/assets/vendor/ckeditor5 or npm i src/assets/vendor/ckeditor5
4. wait for installing......
5. in my .vue file

```
<template>
  <ckes v-model="temp.value" :editor="ClassicEditor" />
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
  import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'
  import 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor'

  const ckes = CKEditor.component
  const ClassicEditor = window['ClassicEditor']
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the [doc](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/installation/getting-started/frameworks/vuejs-v3.html#using-es6-modules) is showing very clearly. First, you need to register Ckeditor as a Vue plugin:

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';

createApp( { /* options */ } ).use( CKEditor ).mount( /* DOM element */ );
```

Then you can use it in your component:

```
<script setup>
  import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor';
</script>
<template>
  <ckeditor :editor="Editor"></ckeditor>
</template>
```

Comment: I'm receiving this error when I try to import online build js `export 'default' (imported as 'Editor') was not found in '.RelaEditor/scripts/ckeditor' (module has no exports)` but I don't have a problem with ck default build `import inlineEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-inline'
` . V35

Answer (score 0):

You have to import it like this.

After installing these packages

```bash
npm install --save @ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue @ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-classic
```

You can use it in two ways.

1. Registering the component globally.
2. Using the component when needed.

#### 1. Registering the component globally:

import the script like this.

```js
import { createApp } from 'vue';
import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';

createApp( { /* options */ } ).use( CKEditor ).mount( /* DOM element */ );
```

Thats all, it has been registered, and now `<ckeditor>` will be automatically identified.

#### 2. Using the component when needed:

Import the script like this.

```html
<script setup>
import { component as CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue'

const CKEditorConfig = reactive({
    editor: ClassicEditor,
    editorData: '<p>Content of the editor.</p>',
    editorConfig: {
    }
})
</script>

<template>
   <div>
       <CKEditor :editor="CKEditorConfig.editor" v-model="CKEditorConfig.editorData" :config="CKEditorConfig.editorConfig"></CKEditor>
   </div>
</template>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me was in the vite config.

Add to your vite config then follow normal ckeditor vue install instructions.

```
 optimizeDeps: {
        include: ['ckeditor5-custom-build']
    },
    build: {
        commonjsOptions: {
            exclude: ['ckeditor5-custom-build']
        }
    },
```

Answer from stackoverflow user Gabriel Silva

[Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js' does not provide an export named 'default'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74559310/uncaught-syntaxerror-the-requested-module-ckeditor5-build-ckeditor-js-does-n)