# Uncaught SyntaxError: The requested module '/ckeditor5/build/ckeditor.js' does not provide an export named 'default'

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor

I'm building SPA website with VueJS for frontend and Laravel for backend. Now I want to add CKEditor custom build to Vue, I have do following steps in CKEditor Documentation, but I received this error:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFNv9.png)

Here is my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQk9x.png)

I'm using Vite instead of Webpack, Is it make problem?

I want to use CKEditor custom build in my vue app

Answer (score 3):

I dont know why but it seems that importing import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build/build/ckeditor'; is the problem so, after looking on multiple sites i have found this solution that worked form me (spa laravel-vue using vite).

First of all to solve the does not provide an export name 'default' is to modify the vite.config.js (only add the optimizeDeps and build props to the defineConfig, the other props shouldnt )

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        vue(),
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js'
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
    ],
    optimizeDeps: {
        include: ['ckeditor5-custom-build']
    },
    build: {
        commonjsOptions: {
            exclude: ['ckeditor5-custom-build']
        }
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
        alias: {
            '@': '/resources/js'
        }
    }
});
```

This should fix the 'default' error, but if you keep having some error on the component i found that importing Editor has some problems so its necesary to change the way of importing it.

```
<template>
    <ckeditor
        :editor="editor"
    />
</template>

<script setup>
    import { shallowRef } from 'vue';
    import CKEditor from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-vue';
    // removing the /build/ckeditor, so you must keep all the content of the online build tool
    import Editor from 'ckeditor5-custom-build';

    const props = defineProps({
        modelValue: {
            type: String,
            required: true
        }
    });

    // Editor seems to be and object and the property :editor expect an function, so if you make an console.log(Editor) would notice that Editor has te property Editor.
    const editor = shallowRef(Editor.Editor);
    const ckeditor = shallowRef(CKEditor.component);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error but with ReactJS maybe it's work for you also. Instead of make a classic import:

```
import Editor from '../../path'
```

Just import directly like:

```
import from '../../path/'
```

After this, you can use `ClassicEditor` in your `<Ckeditor />` component. Here's the full example that works to me:

```
import { CKEditor } from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-react';
import 'react-markdown-editor-lite/lib/index.css';
import '../../ckeditor5/build/ckeditor';

const RichText = ({ data }) => {
  return (
    <CKEditor
      editor={ClassicEditor}
      data={data}
      onChange={(_, editor) => {
        const data = editor.getData();
        console.log(data);
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default RichText;
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me. I am using Vite and Laravel.